# How do I annotate a JAXB property to use xsd:time rather than xsd:datetime?

Tags: java, xsd, types, jaxb, jax-ws

I have a JAXB class like this:

```
public class Game {
    private Date startTime;

    @XmlElement
    public Date getStartTime() {
        return startTime;
    }

    public void setStartTime(Date startTime) {
        this.startTime = startTime;
    }
}
```

which results in an `.xsd` where startTime has type `xsd:datetime`. I want it to be `xsd:time`. `xsd:time` maps to `XmlGregorianCalendar`, but the reverse mapping maps to `xsd:anySimpleType` which isn't very helpful.

I've tried various arguments to `@XmlElement(type=...)` to no avail. Any pointers would be greatly appreciated.

If it makes a difference, this is a type used by JAX-WS.

Comment: I'm not clear if you're trying to generate Java from XSD, or generate XSD from java?

Comment: @skaffman: xsd from java

Comment: If you want to keep `startTime` as `Date` type, have a look at this [post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2519432/jaxb-unmarshal-timestamp). It defines a mapping between `Date` and `String`, that is used to serialize the actual `Date` type.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you are generating the schema from the Java classes here is what you should change:

```
public class Game {
    private XMLGregorianCalendar startTime;

    @XmlElement
    @XmlSchemaType(name = "time")
    public XMLGregorianCalendar getStartTimeForSchema() {
      return startTime;
    }

    public void setStartTimeForSchema(XMLGregorianCalendar startTime) {
      this.startTime = startTime;
    }

    @XmlTransient
    public Date getStartTime() {
      return startTime.toGregorianCalendar().getTime();
    }

    @XmlTransient
    public void setStartTime(Date startTime) {
    GregorianCalendar gc = (GregorianCalendar) GregorianCalendar.getInstance();
      gc.setTime(startTime);
      DatatypeFactory dataTypeFactory = null;
      try {
        dataTypeFactory = DatatypeFactory.newInstance();
      } catch (DatatypeConfigurationException ex) {
        // log
      }
      this.startTime = dataTypeFactory.newXMLGregorianCalendar(gc);
    }
}
```

Comment: Looking good. I'd completely missed XmlSchemaType (perhaps since it's not mentioned in the jax-ws docs on annotations: https://jax-ws.dev.java.net/jax-ws-ea3/docs/annotations.html

My only problem now is to convert a `Date` to an `XMLGregorianCalendar` - not so easy considering how pathologically insane Java's Date handling is.

Comment: Thanks for all your help. 
This would be better for the first line of setStartTime(): Calendar gc = GregorianCalendar.getInstance();