# jaxb unmarshal timestamp

Tags: java, datetime, jaxb

I cannot get JAXB to unmarshal a timestamp in a Resteasy JAX-RS server application.

My class looks like this:

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.NONE)
@XmlRootElement(name = "foo")
public final class Foo {
    // Other fields omitted

    @XmlElement(name = "timestamp", required = true)
    protected Date timestamp;

    public Foo() {}

    public Date getTimestamp() {
        return timestamp;
    }

    public String getTimestampAsString() {
        return (timestamp != null) ? new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss").format(timestamp) : null;
    }

    public void setTimestamp(final Date timestamp) {
        this.timestamp = timestamp;
    }

    public void setTimestamp(final String timestampAsString) {
        try {
            this.timestamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss").parse(timestampAsString);
        } catch (ParseException ex) {
            this.timestamp = null;
        }
    }
}
```

Any ideas?

Thanks.

Answer (score 107, accepted):

JAXB can handle the java.util.Date class.  However it expects the format:

"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss" instead of "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"

If you want to use that date format I would suggest using an XmlAdapter, it would look something like the following:

```
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;

import javax.xml.bind.annotation.adapters.XmlAdapter;

public class DateAdapter extends XmlAdapter<String, Date> {

    private SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");

    @Override
    public String marshal(Date v) throws Exception {
        return dateFormat.format(v);
    }

    @Override
    public Date unmarshal(String v) throws Exception {
        return dateFormat.parse(v);
    }

}
```

You would then specify this adapter on your timestamp property:

```
import java.util.Date;

import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessorType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlElement;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.adapters.XmlJavaTypeAdapter;

@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.NONE) 
@XmlRootElement(name = "foo") 
public final class Foo { 
    // Other fields omitted 

    @XmlElement(name = "timestamp", required = true) 
    @XmlJavaTypeAdapter(DateAdapter.class)
    protected Date timestamp; 

    public Foo() {} 

    public Date getTimestamp() { 
        return timestamp; 
    } 

    public void setTimestamp(final Date timestamp) { 
        this.timestamp = timestamp; 
    } 

}
```

Comment: I actually figured out how to do the translation using @XmlJavaTypeAdapter. With this, I have been able to adapter several different Java classes that required special treatment in my code. Thanks.

Comment: You need to be very careful with SimpleDateformat as it is not threadsafe! I'm not sure if JAXB creates a new object everytime for the adapter.

Comment: For more information see:  http://bdoughan.blogspot.com/2011/01/jaxb-and-datetime-properties.html

Comment: @Gepsens - If you're interested in learning more about `XmlAdapter` I have quite a few examples on my blog: http://blog.bdoughan.com/search/label/XmlAdapter

Comment: Oh thanks, I ended up using your code and adapted it for the Time (sql package) class. Your article is very nice, I usually tweak the jaxb code to my needs when which I know is bad practice compared to using bindings.

Comment: "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss"  is the magic sauce to get an iOS NSDate to upload properly to a RESTEasy jax-rs generated java.util.Date without any futzing around.

Comment: Put the XMLJavaTypeAdapter on the getter if using JPA annotations in the same class: http://www.objectpartners.com/2010/01/25/using-jpa-and-jaxb-annotations-in-the-same-object/

Comment: I suggest setting the timezone on the SimpleDateFormat to avoid varying results depending on the current locale.

Comment: Do you know why the `T` separator is mandatory in JAXB? [It seems to be optional (by "mutual agreement") in the ISO 8601 standard](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601#Combined_date_and_time_representations)

Answer (score 11):

JAXB cannot marshal `Date` objects directly, because they don't have enough information to be unambiguous. JAXB introduced the [`XmlGregorianCalendar`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/xml/datatype/XMLGregorianCalendar.html) class for this purpose, but it's very unpleasant to use directly.

I Suggest changing your `timestamp` field to be a `XmlGregorianCalendar`, and change your various methods to update this field while retaining the public interface you already have, where possible.

If you want to keep the `Date` field, then you'll need to implement your own [`XmlAdapter`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/xml/bind/annotation/adapters/XmlAdapter.html) class to tell JAXB to how turn your `Date` to and from XML.

Comment: JAXB can certainly marshal java.util.Date, only the format is "yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss" matching xsd:dateTime.  The EclipseLink JAXB implementation (MOXy) can also handle the java.sql.Date/Time/Timestamp types.

Answer (score 3):

In order to get the XML marshaller to generate an xsd:date formatted as YYYY-MM-DD without defining an XmlAdapter I used this method to build an instance of javax.xml.datatype.XMLGregorianCalendar:

```
public XMLGregorianCalendar buildXmlDate(Date date) throws DatatypeConfigurationException {
    return date==null ? null : DatatypeFactory.newInstance().newXMLGregorianCalendar(new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd").format(date));
}
```

With the result I initialized the XMLGregorianCalendar field of the class generated by JAXB compiler (in Eclipse):

```
  Date now = new Date();
  ...
  report.setMYDATE(buildXmlDateTime(now));
  ...
  JAXBContext context = JAXBContext.newInstance(ReportType.class);
  Marshaller m = context.createMarshaller();
  m.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, true);
  m.marshal(new ObjectFactory().createREPORT(report), writer);
```

And obtained the tag formatted as expected:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<REPORT>
   ...
   <MY_DATE>2014-04-30</MY_DATE>
   ...
</REPORT>
```

Answer (score 3):

Using this adapter should be thread safe:

```
public class DateXmlAdapter extends XmlAdapter<String, Date> {

    /**
     * Thread safe {@link DateFormat}.
     */
    private static final ThreadLocal<DateFormat> DATE_FORMAT_TL = new ThreadLocal<DateFormat>() {

        @Override
        protected DateFormat initialValue() {
            return new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss");
        }

    };

    @Override
    public Date unmarshal(String v) throws Exception {
        return DATE_FORMAT_TL.get().parse(v);
    }

    @Override
    public String marshal(Date v) throws Exception {
        return DATE_FORMAT_TL.get().format(v);
    }

}
```

Comment: I got the following error: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 0; columnNumber: 0; cvc-datatype-valid.1.2.1: '05/10/2017 00:00:00' is not a valid value for 'dateTime'

Comment: your string  '05/10/2017 00:00:00' has not the format expected: "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss" - you should either change input or format

Comment: INFRAXML 2.2: javax.xml.bind.MarshalException
 - with linked exception:
[org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 0; columnNumber: 0; cvc-datatype-valid.1.2.1: '2017-10-10T14:59:34' is not a valid value for 'date'.]