# Jersey Marshall Map<Date,List>

Tags: date, dictionary, jaxb, jersey

I start understanding how jersey works with JAXB. But today i faced  a particular case where i want to marshall a Map of (Date,List) entries:

```
@XmlRootElement
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class MyClass{
  @XmlJavaTypeAdapter(MapAdapter.class)
  private Map<Date,List<MyObject>> = new TreeMap<Date,List<MyObject>>(new DateCompareDesc());
}
```

The goal here is to marshall a Map whose entry is a Date with its corresponding list of MyObject. the map is sorted in desc order.

For this i implemented an Adapter for Map (MapAdapter, following @Blaise Doughan's tutorial, http://blog.bdoughan.com/2010/07/xmladapter-jaxbs-secret-weapon.html). The problem is on the Date key. I have an Error : Unable to marshall java.util.Date. So i tried this new Date Adapter :

```
public class DateAdapter extends XmlAdapter<String, Date> {

@Override
public Date unmarshal(String v) throws Exception {
   //not implemented
}

@Override
public String marshal(Date v) throws Exception {
    return v.toString();
}

}
```

Where can i add  @XmlJavaTypeAdapter(DateAdapter.class) so that Jersey could marhsall Date as key to my TreeMap?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

JAXB supports the marshalling/unmarshalling of `java.util.Date` to the standard XML schema types:  date, time, dateTime.  You can control the type used with the `@XmlSchemaType` annotation.

- http://blog.bdoughan.com/2011/01/jaxb-and-datetime-properties.html

If your date information is not represented as one of the standard XML schema types, you can use an `XmlAdapter` similar to the one I used the following answer to a similar question:

- [jaxb unmarshal timestamp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2519432/jaxb-unmarshal-timestamp/3181966#3181966)

If you need to use the `XmlAdapter` approach, the `@XmlJavaTypeAdapter` annotation would be placed on the `Date` field of the adapted object representing the entry in the `Map`.  Below is what this might look like based on my blog:  http://blog.bdoughan.com/2010/07/xmladapter-jaxbs-secret-weapon.html.

```
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlValue;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAttribute;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.adapters.XmlJavaTypeAdapter;

public class MyMapEntryType {

   @XmlAttribute
   @XmlJavaTypeAdapter(DateAdapter.class)
   public Date key;

   public List<MyObject> value;

}
```

Comment: Hi Blaise, thanks for your response. In my case i have a Map<Date,List>. Date and List are not comming from another class on which i could add appropriate annotations. So is it not possible to annotate that Map to Adapth the Date and List?

Comment: @Lahniep - You are using the default representation of Map?  Also how is your date information formatted?

Comment: Yes .. it is a TreeMap and the date is formated with  SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss")

Comment: If all you Date objects are formatted that way you could register the XmlAdapter at the package level.  Here is an example:  http://blog.bdoughan.com/2011/05/jaxb-and-joda-time-dates-and-times.html

Comment: I am using Eclipse and i got error"Package annotations must be in file package-info.java" when adding this : @XmlJavaTypeAdapters({@XmlJavaTypeAdapter(type=Date.class,value=DateAdapter.class)}) before package declaration of my java file. ??

Comment: @Lahniep - Yes the annotations will need to go in a class called `package-info`.  In the blog post I linked to the content of this class will look like the code under the "Registering the XmlAdapters" section.

Comment: I've added the package-info.java class  and it seems to work on a dummy test class. But when i use it on my Map object i obtain this error : java.lang.NullPointerException
 at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.reflect.TransducedAccessor.get(TransducedAccessor.java:169)