# How to convert TemporalType.TIMESTAMP to Date() in Java?

Tags: java, sql, timestamp

I have an `@Entity`

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "variable")
@XmlRootElement
public class Variable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private long id;

    @Column(unique = true, nullable = false)
    private String name;

    @Column
    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    private VariableType type;

    @Column(nullable = false)
    private String units;

    @Column
    private String description;

    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    @Column(name = "created_on", nullable = false)
    private Date createdOn;

    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    @Column(name = "retired_on", nullable = true)
    private Date retiredOn;

    @Column(nullable = false)
    private boolean core;
}
```

When I insert data using `VariableManager`, it goes correctly inside database

```
variableCrudService.create(new Variable(name, type, units, description, new Date(), core));
```

and I can see that in logs

```
 added variable id=13 name=v4 type=String units=u4 description=created with web service createdOn=2013-01-14 14:43:57.0 retiredOn=null core=true
```

and in database
mysql> select * from variable;

```
+----+------+------------+-------+--------------------------+---------------------+------------+------+
| id | name | type       | units | description              | created_on          | retired_on | core |
+----+------+------------+-------+--------------------------+---------------------+------------+------+
|  1 | v1   | Double     | u1    | created via migration    | 2013-01-14 13:15:19 | NULL       |    1 |
|  2 | v2   | String     | u2    | created via migration    | 2013-01-14 13:15:19 | NULL       |    1 |
|  3 | v3   | BigDecimal | u3    | created via migration    | 2013-01-14 13:15:19 | NULL       |    0 |
| 12 | v4   | String     | u4    | created with web service | 2013-01-14 14:41:31 | NULL       |    1 |
+----+------+------------+-------+--------------------------+---------------------+------------+------+
4 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

but when I test this using curl, I get timestamps in weird format

```
[
    {
        "core": true, 
        "createdOn": 1358198119000, 
        "description": "created via migration", 
        "id": 1, 
        "name": "v1", 
        "retiredOn": null, 
        "type": "Double", 
        "units": "u1"
    }, 
    {
        "core": true, 
        "createdOn": 1358198119000, 
        "description": "created via migration", 
        "id": 2, 
        "name": "v2", 
        "retiredOn": null, 
        "type": "String", 
        "units": "u2"
    }, 
    {
        "core": false, 
        "createdOn": 1358198119000, 
        "description": "created via migration", 
        "id": 3, 
        "name": "v3", 
        "retiredOn": null, 
        "type": "BigDecimal", 
        "units": "u3"
    }, 
    {
        "core": true, 
        "createdOn": 1358203437000, 
        "description": "created with web service", 
        "id": 13, 
        "name": "v4", 
        "retiredOn": null, 
        "type": "String", 
        "units": "u4"
    }
]
```

What is going around here? What is that I am doing wrong here?

Comment: Do you have solution for this problem? I'm Struggling with this.. Can u please help?

Answer (score 0):

I think the date value is right, but perhaps not in the format you want. You can try to create a custom date adapter to ensure JAXB unmarshal the value in the right format. Take a look at this: [jaxb unmarshal timestamp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2519432/jaxb-unmarshal-timestamp)