# Jersey how to annotate java.sql.Timestamp object

Tags: java, rest, jaxb, jersey

**Background**

I have a Root element class which contains variable of the class `java.sql.Timestamp`, I want JAXB to create xml element from that variable.

**What I have tried**

- I create class adapter which is.

> import java.sql.Date;
>
> import java.sql.Timestamp;
>
> import javax.xml.bind.annotation.adapters.XmlAdapter;

```
public class TimestampAdapter extends XmlAdapter <Date, Timestamp> {
```

> ```
>   public Date marshal(Timestamp v) {
>       return new Date(v.getTime());
>   }
>
>   public Timestamp unmarshal(Date v) {
>       return new Timestamp(v.getTime());
>   }
> ```
>
> }

- . Then I annotate the function which gets that variable:

> @XmlJavaTypeAdapter(TimestampAdapter.class)
>   public java.sql.Timestamp getEndDate() {
>
> if (endDate == null)
>
> retrieveInfo();
>
> return endDate;

}

> **Problem**

I still get this exception

```
java.sql.Date does not have a no-arg default constructor.
```

Also I have checked [This Thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2519432/jaxb-unmarshal-timestamp), but it is talking about String to TimeStamp, not my case.

Any help would be appreciated.

**EDIT**

This variable is in the class `OrderStatus`, I call it from class `OrderImpl` like this

```
@Override
    @XmlElement(name = "Status", type = OrderStatus.class)
    public OrderStatus getStatus() {
        return status;
    }
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [jaxb unmarshal timestamp](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2519432/jaxb-unmarshal-timestamp)

Comment: @BlaiseDoughan It is not duplicated, please check the question, It is about `java.sql.date`, not `java.util.date`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your `XmlAdapter` should convert the `Timestamp` to/from `java.util.Date` instead of `java.sql.Date`.

Comment: Thanks for ur answer, I am trying it.

Comment: I didn't get the exception, but also I didn't get any results in my browser when trying to call that service. Forthermore, when I tried to call that function locally `public static voic main`, I got the correct data (+1).

Comment: I got results in my browser for each other variables in my class, except `EndDate`, It seems like this method isn't triggered itself

Comment: I added some information to the question which might be helpful.

Comment: @WilliamKinaan - What if you try a standalone JAXB example outside of JAX-RS to test your mappings.  You can set a `ValidationEventHandler` on the `Unmarahaller` to catch any problems.

Comment: It works buddy, I was calling it `return status` without making new, thanks to your help.

Comment: When using java.sql.Date, it gives null pointer exception. Don't forget use java.util.Date because Timestamp extends java.util.Date

Answer (score 2):

Your adapter needs to be like this:

```
public class TimestampAdapter extends XmlAdapter<Date, Timestamp> {
      public Date marshal(Timestamp v) {
          return new Date(v.getTime());
      }
      public Timestamp unmarshal(Date v) {
          return new Timestamp(v.getTime());
      }
  }
```

and

```
@XmlJavaTypeAdapter( TimestampAdapter.class)
        public Timestamp done_date;
```

Comment: As I have mentioned in the question, I have seen this answer, It is not my case, I get this exception `DateAdapter is not applicable to the field type java.sql.Timestamp. `

Comment: I have already tried your solution, I mention that in the question. It was just that the question didn't show `<Date, Timestamp>`, Now I edit it

Comment: sorry, I should have made it clear. I think the problem is because you did not mention the types being converted. I have added that in my answer

Comment: Thanks to your efforts, +1