# Unmarshalling custom date to XMLGregorianCalendar

Tags: xml, jaxb, xsd

We are unmarshalling date field using JAXB. The format that is coming in the xml is like

> 2013-10-07 03:57:36.703

In my DTO class, the field where this value has to be populates looks like

```
@XmlElement(name = "VALID_TO", required = true)
@XmlSchemaType(name = "date")
protected XMLGregorianCalendar validto;
```

But, after unmarshalling, I don't get anything in     valito.

In the xsd, `VALID_TO` has a custom `xsd:date` mapping with pattern`[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2}`

Is it necessary to have timeZone in the value to be able to convert to XmlGregorianCalendar ?

Thanks !!!

Comment: possible duplicate of [jaxb unmarshal timestamp](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2519432/jaxb-unmarshal-timestamp)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following formats will work with `JAXB` and `XMLGregorianCalendar` out of the box.

- xsd:date - `2013-10-07`
- xsd:dateTime - `2013-10-07T03:57:36.703`

If you want an alternate format such as `2013-10-07 03:57:36.703` you can use an `XmlAdapter`.

- [jaxb unmarshal timestamp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2519432/jaxb-unmarshal-timestamp/3181966#3181966)