# JacksonJaxbJsonProvider date format

Tags: java, json, jackson, cxf, simpledateformat

We are using CXF in combination with Jackson (JacksonJaxbJsonProvider) to marshall domain objects into JSON. Everything is working good, with the exception that I cannot get dates to format the way I want them to. In short, what I want, is to output dates as **seconds since epoch** (also called unix time). This is partly doable with `SerializationConfig.Feature.WRITE_DATES_AS_TIMESTAMPS`, but this gives me **milliseconds**, not **seconds**. As my dates don't have such high precision (and never will), I am wasting 4 bytes for every timestamp.

To my knowledge, the only way I can control the date format is by using `setDateFormat()` on `ObjectMapper`. This function accepts a `DateFormat`. However, it does not seem like a `DateFormat` can output **seconds** since epoch, only **milliseconds**.

Are there any other ways of doing this?

Comment: You'd need to write a custom serializer/deserializer. But why is it so important? Just `/ 1000` in your code...

Comment: It's important because I need to minimize the amount of data as much as possible. It also feels wrong to send unnecessary large amounts of data to the clients just because CXF/Jackson says so. If you feel a custom serializer/deserializer is the best bet, could you perhaps come up with an answer? That way I could mark it as correct :)

Comment: An XmlAdapter is what you want.  Check this out: http://stackoverflow.com/a/3181966.