# Jersey (MOXy) truncating JSON dates

Tags: java, json, jersey-2.0, moxy

I am using Jersey 1.21.1 and am getting strange behavior when unmarshalling dates.

Simplified version of my POJO:

```
@XmlRootElement
public class Invoice {
    private Date invoiceDate;
    private Date invoiceDate2;
}
```

My resource method:

```
@PUT
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public Response putInvoice(Invoice invoice) { .. }
```

The JavaScript code that calls this service uses `JSON.stringify` to produce  the following HTTP request payload (this is what was actually sent, according to the Chrome debugger):

> {"invoiceDate":"2015-10-27T04:00:00.000Z","invoiceDate2":"2015-10-27T08:00:00.000Z"}

So far so good. But when I stop at a breakpoint inside of `putInvoice` and examine the Java dates invoice.invoiceDate and invoice.invoiceDate2, they both have the same fastTime:

> 1445904000000

(which equals October 27, 2015 12:00:00 AM UTC).

I am at a loss why Jersey/MOXy are seemingly unable to parse what looks to me like a standard ISO UTC date. I can only assume I'm doing something wrong or making a bad assumption. Help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The root cause of the problem was that my POJO date field was declared to be `java.sql.Date`, rather than `java.util.Date`. The ISO format is indeed parsed correctly when unmarshalling to `java.util.Date`.

The obvious solution is to use `java.util.Date` in the POJO. But if for some reason a `java.sql.Date` is needed, you can write a custom `XmlAdaptor` to do the parsing and formatting (see answer to this SO question: [jaxb unmarshal timestamp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2519432/jaxb-unmarshal-timestamp_))

Additional comments: it's not all that surprising that `java.sql.Date` doesn't work with Jersey/MOXy out of the box, but I do find the specific failure surprising. Frankly I would have both expected and preferred a class conversion exception, like the one I got when I attempted to write my own `XmlAdaptor`. That's how I eventually figured out the root cause.

Since MOXy truncated the time, I'm wondering if that's because an exception in the default date-time parsing causes MOXy to fall back to date-only. But if so, how did that fallback successfully assign to `java.sql.Date` when the original logic couldn't? It's a mystery but not one I plan to spend any time on. (Edit: this explanation probably is wrong-- see comment)

Comment: Something else I should have noticed before: Jersey + MOXy does the exact same truncation when it marshals java.sql.Date. That is, when I do an HTTP GET on the resource, the date string has no time component or timezone, e.g. '2015-12-15'. So my speculation above that this was inadvertently caused by exception handling seems wrong. It's consistent and therefore feels deliberate, but I am at a loss to explain why java.sql.Date would be treated this way.